# How would one translate 'I showed signs of needing something' into German?

Tags: english-to-german, progressive

Translating (irony intended) the **progressive tense** always gets me. I've looked at this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/German/comments/2s06rd/how_to_translate_english_gerund_verbs_into_german/) and understand that the progressive tense is usually translated into **Präsens**. I can only come up with:

> Ich zeigte Zeichnen, irgendwas zu benötigen

but this sounds strange to me.

I also know that:

> There are *no* Progressive Tenses in German. The distinction between the English progressive present tense ‘He is singing well’ (i.e. at the moment) and the simple present tense ‘He sings well’ (i.e. usually) cannot be expressed by using different forms of the verb in German. In most
>   contexts, the distinction is simply ignored in German and ‘Er singt gut’ is used for both these English sentences.     *- Hammer's German Grammar and Usage*

Comment: Where is your present in the translation?

Comment: As for "there is no progressive tense in German": did you consider the (admittedly non-standard, but anyway very popular) *Er ist am Singen* form? (*Was macht iher? - Wir sind am Arbeiten. Die anderen sind am Marmeladekochen.)

Comment: Further to what @Christian Geiselmann said, you CAN use the participle in German, too. While ‚?Er ist singend‘ und ‚?Er ist ein Singender‘ aren’t possible, you could have: ‚Was macht er gerade?‘ – ‚Er sitzt **fröhlich singend** am Tisch.‘ Similarly, ‚Er ist gerade beim Singen‘ is also possible.
One more interesting example. Suppose you want to translate ‘Where is John?’ – ‘He’s gone shopping.’ This would be: ‘Wo ist John?’ – ‘Er ist gerade (beim) Einkaufen.’ So here it’s the German, not the English, that uses the present tense to express an action in progress/a current state.

Comment: FYI: that Reddit thread is utterly wrong in almost everything. Even the part about English.

Comment: My first thought was "Ich machte Anzeichen, irgendetwas zu brauchen". (Native German speaker). However, stuffing the verb "machen" into every sentence where you do not know any better verb may be ugly.

Comment: @MarkOxford: "While 'Er ist singend' und 'Er ist ein Singender' aren’t possible" - I would even distinguish further by saying that these two forms are indeed grammatical (as opposed to, for instance, 'Er ist singende'), even though they are not used and considered bad style/absolutely unidiomatic. Note that especially the second construction is indeed used sometimes, be it for reasons of gender-neutral language (*Studierende*) or due to lack of an alternative word (*Sehende* vs. Blinde).

Comment: @O. R. Mapper Agreed: by ‘aren’t possible’ I meant aren’t idiomatic/felicitous. (Although, ‘Er ist singend’ is so unidiomatic, it borders on the false.) Regarding ‘Studierende’ and ‘Sehende’: while they are used (for the reasons you mention), many find them artificial / forced / linguistically clumsy – exactly because these words mean that the person in question is *currently* studying / seeing. E.g., students on holiday are still Studenten (or Studentinnen), but not Studierende.

Comment: @MarkOxford: "because these words mean that the person in question is *currently* studying / seeing" - while I agree especially *Studierende* feels artificial/linguistically clumsy, I think that very narrow interpretation of the attribute *currently* applying is questionable. Claiming that "students on holiday are still Studenten (or Studentinnen), but not Studierende" is like assuming "Ich habe von 2001 bis 2005 studiert." means that I studied nonstop, without sleeping or any other breaks, for 5 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dein "Ich zeigte Zeichen..." ist eine wörtliche Übersetzung, bei der man die Herkunft aus dem Englischen/Amerikanischen drei Meilen gegen den Wind riecht. Im eigentlichen deutschen Sprachraum würde so etwas keiner sagen.

Etablierte Formen, einen Gedanken dieser Art (prozesshafter Beginn einer Tätigkeit oder eines Zustands) auszudrücken, wären:

> Ich fing an, Hunger zu kriegen.
>
> Ich begann, mich nach Ruhe zu sehnen.
>
> Allmählich wurde ich durstig. [Präteritum!]
>
> Allmählich werde ich durstig. [Präsens!]
>
> Allmählich machte sich bei mir die Müdigkeit bemerkbar. [Präteritum!]
>
> Allmählich macht sich bei mir die Müdigkeit bemerkbar. [Präsens!]
>
> Seit gestern zeigt er Anzeichen von Heimweh.

Vielleicht gefällt dir '... machte sich xyz bemerkbar' am besten, weil es deinem "showed signs of needing something" nahekommt.

"Zeigt Anzeichen von..." ist zwar im Alltagsleben anzutreffen, ist aber stilistisch unschön wegen der Dopplung "zeigen" und "Zeichen/Anzeichen". 'Zeichen zeigen' zeigt ja starke Anzeichen einer Tautologie...

Das letzte Beispiel ("Seit gestern...") finde ich interessant, weil es Präsens benutzt, aber eine Aussage zur Vergangenheit einschließt - ein typischer Fall fürs Englisch "has been".

---

PS

Es gibt im Schwäbischen (allerdings, meine ich, nur in sehr alten, dörflichen Varianten) eine weitere interessante Form, den prozesshaften Beginn einer Tätigkeit oder eines Zustands zu beschreiben:

> I werr ââfanga duuschtig [Ich werde anfangen durstig]
>
> I bee ââfanga duuschtig [Ich bin anfangen durstig]
>
> I griag ââfanga Duuschd [Ich kriege anfangen Durst]

Heißt jeweils: "Ich fange an, durstig zu werden." / "Allmählich krieg' ich Durst."

> Etz würts ââfanga Naachd [Jetzt wird's anfangen Nacht]

"Es beginnt, dunkel zu werden." / "Es fängt an, Nacht zu werden."

> Etz gôht's mür abbr ââfanga uff da Sagg! [Jetzt geht es mir aber anfangen auf den Sack]

"Jetzt fängt's aber wirklich an, mir auf den Wecker zu gehen!"

Das Besondere daran ist, dass die Infinitiv-Form "anfangen" hier wie ein Adverb verwendet wird.

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort. Welche Beispiel, würden Sie meinen, am besten ausdrücken würde, dass es eigentlich klar war, dass ich etwas benötigte.

Comment: (Please excuse my sh*tty German)

Comment: Ich finde, dass der Anglizismus von "Ich zeigte Zeichen.." eher in der Kombination mit dem Infinitiv liegt, der im Deutschen eher ungebräuchlich ist. Nimmt man stattdessen ein Substantiv, hört sich's schon viel deutscher (wenn auch sehr "amtsdeutsch") an. "Patient zeigt Zeichen von Bierbedarf"

Comment: @TM  - Verzeihung, die Frage habe ich nicht verstanden. Was meinst du  mit "dass es eigentlich klar war, dass ich etwas benötige"? Dies ist doch bei allen Beispielen, die oben aufgeführt sind, der Fall?

Comment: Sorry. "dass es eigentlich **allen** klar war, dass ich etwas benötigte". z.B "Jeder hätte das sehen müssen".

Comment: @TM. Oh. Das verändert die Situation erheblich. In so einem Fall würde man vielleicht sagen: "Es war unübersehbar, dass der Baum an Wassermangel litt." - "Sein Ärger war unüberhörbar." - "Es war völlig klar, das er übermüdet war."

Comment: 'ist aber stilistisch unschön wegen der Dopplung "zeigen" und "Zeichen/Anzeichen' - ich nehme da keine Dopplung wahr, lebe allerdings auch in einer Region, wo *(i)ch* und *g* klar unterschiedlich klingen. Dazu kommt aber meines Erachtens generell noch, dass man normalerweise von *ersten* Anzeichen spricht, wodurch die zwei potenziell ähnlich klingenden Wörter nicht direkt aufeinanderfolgen.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like (Germans like Substantives)

> Ich bemerkte an mir Zeichen von -[Not|Bedarf|..]

more liberal translation

> Ich fing an einen [Wunsch|Bedarf] nach xxx zu verspüren

or even

> Mir ging auf, dass ich dringend ein Bier brauchte.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the original

> I showed signs of needing something

with your comment

> dass es eigentlich allen klar war, dass ich etwas benötigte". z.B "Jeder hätte das sehen müssen

I find this one the most fitting:

> Man konnte mir ansehen, dass ich etwas brauchte

"showing signs" (and similar phrases, like "it shows") hint at something being visible or noticeable. "Man kann es mir ansehen" quite literally means "looking at me, one can see..."

If you want the EVERYONE should be able to see it, you might alternatively want to go for our version of "obvious":

> Es war offensichtlich, dass ich etwas brauchte

Comment: Die Frage wäre also eigentlich gewesen: Welche anderen Möglichkeiten gibt es, *es ist offensichtlich, dass...* auszudrücken?

Answer (score 1):

as German I would say:

> Ich zeigte Zeichen etwas zu brauchen

but

> Man sah mir an, dass ich etwas brauchte

is translated more freely but sounds way better
but your solution isn't wrong :)